# An element has children, but eq() returns undefined when I try to access them

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a very, very strange issue with my code.

I am trying to loop through some elements (children of a container element) to alter their HTML, however many of them return 'undefined' when I try to access them.

```
for(i=0; i<this.shape.length; i++) {
    alert($('#selected_shape_table *').eq(i).find('div').html()); 
    $('#selected_shape_table *').eq(i).find('div').html("Test"); 
}
```

I have tried a variety of things to try to try to narrow down the issue, but I'm still stumped.

The expected behaviour is for it to loop through each shape, and change the text of each to "Test". The actual behaviour is that it alters half of the elements and does not alter the other half - I added the alert above to return which elements it was accessing, and found that it 'finds' half of them. For example, the return where the elements are Square, Circle, Triangle, Rhombus would be ... Square, undefined, Circle, undefined.

Things I have learned so far are:

- If I check the # of elements using `alert("#selected_shape_table has " + $('#selected_shape_table > *').length + " children.");` it will return the expected number of results.
- If I try to access the elements independently (i.e. `$('#selected_shape_table *').eq(i).find('div').html()` where i is a number specified manually rather than by a loop) it exhibits the same unexpected behaviour - every second element is `undefined`

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

Apologies for not posting markup initially. These shapes are added dynamically, which is why I didn't post it at first.

```
<table id="selected_shape_container">
</table>
```

and the elements are added to it with

`$('#selected_shape_table').append('<td><div id="' + shape + '" class="selected_shape"> d' + shape + '</div></td>');`

Comment: Can we see the markup? JsFiddle the entire lot, please

Comment: It could be that half of them have descendant divs and the other half dont. Without markup, nobody knows.

Comment: `$('#selected_shape_table *')` is not the same as `$('#selected_shape_table > *')`

Comment: Aha - a bit further forward! My mistake... I changed the alert to return `$('#selected_shape_table *') and it returns double the number of children I'd expect...

Comment: What object does `this` refer to in your code above?

Comment: `this` refers to the object the function this code is in is part of, `this.shape` is simply an attribute of the object

Comment: Sorry guys I'm not ignoring the requests for markup - I was trying to try the suggestions for fixes first - adding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `children()`:

```
for(i=0; i<this.shape.length; i++) {
    alert($('#selected_shape_table').children().eq(i).find('div').html()); 
    $('#selected_shape_table').children().eq(i).find('div').html("Test"); 
}
```

Comment: This works, but I have no clue why the element has double the expected number of children, or what was going on...